# Group flutter widgets based on data

Tags: flutter, dart

I have difficulties on how to group sets of flutter widgets based on data returned from server.
The sample data is as below:

```
{
   id: 1,
   group: 1,
   name: A,
},
{
   id: 2,
   group: 1,
   name: B,
},
{
   id: 3,
   group: 2,
   name: C,
},
{
   id: 3,
   group: null,
   name: D,
}
```

Lets say those group that not null will group into a set of Dropdownlist while others are checkboxed, I have been trying so many hours by still cant and I am new to Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a List? You can group by filtering with `where`, i.e., `data.where((x) => x["group"] != null)`.

Full Dart code, see [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev):

```
void main() {
  var data = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "group": 1,
      "name": "A",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "group": 1,
      "name": "B",
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "group": 2,
      "name": "C",
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "group": null,
      "name": "D",
    }
  ];

  print(data.where((x) => x["group"] != null));
}
```

Comment: yes...i need to create list of checkboxes and dropdownlist based on he data.